# MVC URL Redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am currently using a custom MVC Architecture to create my website.

The problem is that when I enter localhost/website/ which in the future would be www.website.com/, I want my homepage to be shown. Currently I am making this work by using localhost/website/home/ but I don't want that, I just want localhost/website/ which automatically shows the homepage.

I have tried to do this with htaccess, but without any success. When I navigate to localhost/website/ it shows me an error 'This webpage is not available'.

My htaccess code: This is found inside my public folder.

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         RewriteEngine On

         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
             RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
            ErrorDocument 404 index.php
        </IfModule>
```

I hope that made some sense and that someone could help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a new rule like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # handle home page
    RewriteRule ^/?$ home [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding, right after the line: `RewriteEngine On` this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?url=home [L]
```